# Bootstrap overrides my CSS even if i follow the thumb rule and applies some rules of it's own for same selectors. How do i totally avoid that?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Yes I did try changing the selectors and used the priority rule as well but still, it's applying some of its own rules.

Example

my custom CSS

```
 .modal-content{
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: 20% auto;
padding: 10px;
width: 50%;
overflow: auto;
}
```

BootStrap overriding my CSS and applying some rules which I don't want to use!

```
.modal-content{
position: relative;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
border: 1px solid #999;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
border-radius: 6px;
outline: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

I don't want the second part of the code which is BootStrap's CSS to be applied to my code. What do i do?

Comment: From what you have it looks like it's the same specificity, which means whichever one is loaded second gets priority. If you don't want ANY of the bootstrap styles to be applied, then you will have to override all of the styles provided by bootstrap unless you want to edit the bootstrap css file.

Comment: As I specified I've used the thumb rule and my CSS comes after the bootstrap one. Still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must override those specific properties from the old ruleset. Properties from rulesets higher up in the cascade will still apply unless redeclared lower in the cascade.

In order to stop the border, box shadow and other bootstrap properties from applying, your custom CSS should be:

```
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 20% auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: auto;

  /* override bootstrap styles */
  position: static;
  -webkit-background-clip: none;
  background-clip: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: so invariably I have to provide all the attributes that bootstrap is overriding in my CSS? And as you've mentioned redeclaring it lower in the cascade? FYI your solution did work.

Comment: Yeah, that's how CSS works. It's the individual properties that cascade, not rulesets as a whole. If you found my answer helpful please click the accept button

Comment: Thank you appreciate it!